# Thread safety of static variable initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to find out whether 2 calls to `Get()` with different parameter types in the code below are thread-safe:

```
struct MethodTypeIndex
{
    template <typename T>
    static size_t Get(T)
    {
        static size_t index = NextIndex();
        return index;
    }
private:
    static size_t NextIndex()
    {
        static size_t nextIndex = 0;
        return nextIndex++;
    }
};
```

On the one hand, `NextIndex()` is called during the initialization of `index` and according to standard:

```
§6.7 [stmt.dcl] p4
```

> If control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is
>   being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion
>   of the initialization.

On the other hand, I don't know if call to `NextIndex()` is considered as part of initialization of `index`. And if not, does brace-initialization make difference?

```
static size_t index{ NextIndex() };
```

Or is there any other ways to make it thread safe, if I don't want to make  `nextIndex` atomic?

Comment: The full expression of the right-hand side of that `=` is "part of initialization". Including the function calls.

Comment: `NextIndex()` call is part of the initialization of `index`. But, if you call `Get<T>` and `Get<U>` with different parameter types, you call two different, independent instantiations of `Get`, each with its own `index`. The two initializations of these two independent instances of `index` are not synchronized.

Comment: And if there was not a template, the code would be thread-safe and additional call to `NextIndex()` in copy-assignment initialization doesn't change it in any way?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik but wouldn't the instantiation of `nextIndex` be synchronised?

Comment: @SirGuy `nextIndex++` isn't?

Comment: @SirGuy `nextIndex = 0` would be. `nextIndex++` would not. That's a data race waiting to happen.

Comment: @user2198121 What is this "copy assignment initialization" of which you speak? What "additional call to `NextIndex()`"? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Will calls to `Get()` be thread safe in this code? https://pastebin.com/izXnNWJt

Comment: @user2198121 Yes it would be thread-safe, assuming there are no other calls to `NextIndex()` besides the one shown. Note however that `NextIndex()` will only get called once, and `Get()` will always return zero. Which is probably not quite what you had in mind.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik No, that's what I wanted to know, thank you.

Comment: Why are you playing premature optimization with standardese? Just use `std::atomic_size_t`. It has an `operator++` and everything.

Comment: @StoryTeller In my project I did. But it was interesting for me.

Comment: Good to know such code is not in production. It's a good question, otherwise. Carry on then.

Answer (score 17):

Pretend for a moment that you have two different functions:

```
static size_t get_int() {
    static size_t index = NextIndex();
    return index;
}
static size_t get_long() {
    static size_t index = NextIndex();
    return index;
}
```

Is there any doubt in your mind that calling these two functions from separate threads is **not** thread-safe? Clearly there’s a data race in the calls to `NextIndex`.

Creating those functions by instantiating a template function doesn’t get rid of the data race. Templates **are not code**; they are **patterns** for **creating** code. Calling two different instantiations of your template function (for example, `Get<int>()` and `Get<long>()`) from two different threads produces a data race.

Comment: Could you please add that `NextIndex()` call is part of initialization and calls to it on themself are threadsafe?